# Docker in Docker docker-compose daemon not running on host. Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Running docker in docker image (dind), on windows 10. Powershell is run as admin. I have a manager and a worker up container up through `docker-compose.yml` file.

The compose yaml file is as such:

```
version: '2'
  services:
    manager:
      image: docker:latest
      ports:
        - "2375"
        - "8080"
      privileged: true
      tty: true
    worker:
      image: docker:latest
      ports:
        - "8080"
      privileged: true
      tty: true
```

I don't know why or what tty: true even does but it's the only way to get it to stay up for some reason.

I try to init the manager with:

```
docker-compose exec manager docker swarm init --listen-addr 0.0.0.0:2377
```

I also tried with the port being 0.0.0.0:2375 as what is open in the compose yaml.

When I run the command and get this:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Here is the result of a docker-compose ps

```
Name                   Command           State                        Ports
swarmtest_manager_1 docker-entrypoint.sh sh Up 0.0.0.0:32782->2375/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32781->8080/tcp
swarmtest_worker_1  docker-entrypoint.sh sh Up 0.0.0.0:32780->8080/tcp
```

Running and testing services in the dind environment would be ideal, although I still don't like compose as I am trying to learn how to use it better, creating a docker-machine and using the docker swarm mode seems much easier, although I'm truthfully not sure of the limitations with compose in this manner.

Comment: for the yml file white space is correct i just messed up when posting. fyi

Comment: You are trying to run "docker swarm init" inside a docker container. And I guess docker doesn't exists inside the container. It would be strange. Not sure what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Have you tried the same command with `sudo` ?

Comment: mayid im trying to run a swarm inside of a container with compose to spin 2 nodes , manager and worker. I've seen it done on a older version of docker. My issue seems to be that im not sure how to init the daemon in the docker in docker container. Im running this inside of windows, but i can try to use the sudo command to see if the mobyvm accepts it.